# Is there anyway to not include start of file path

Tags: swift, file

Okay so i have project that requires the use of textFile where i store data in.When i pass it to the teacher i do not want the file to reset or give an error due to being unable to find the path is there anyway to accomplish this.(new to swift.)

```
func writeFile()
{
    let str = temp
    let path = "/Users/xdesss/Desktop/Projectv4/Project/holder.txt"
    let filename = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        try str.write(to: filename, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        try print(String(contentsOf: filename))
        print("This Url: \(path)")
    } catch {
        print("fail")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should clarify what you are trying to accomplish; for instance is retrieving the user home directory enough? If say your project is always on the desktop you could use `NSHomeDirectory` and append your relative path instead ( `/Desktop/Projectv4/Project/holder.txt` )

Comment: Use the proper methods of `FileManager` to get the correct path.

Comment: Unrelated but `filename` is a poor choice of name for a variable that represent a full file path URL. The actual filename is just `holder.text`. I would rename your `filename` variable to something like `fileURL`.

Answer (score 0):

`/Desktop/Projectv4/Project/holder.txt` is an absolute path on your local machine. If you run this project in another computer, this path will not exist and the `.txt` file will not be there.

You need to use a relative path, so the `.txt` file will be loaded using the project folder as a base.

In order to achieve this, you can use Swift [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager)

> A convenient interface to the contents of the file system, and the primary means of interacting with it.

Using it, your code would be like this:

```
func writeFile() {
    let str = temp
    let file = "holder.txt"
    let currentDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
    let fileURL = currentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(file)

    do {
        try str.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        try print(String(contentsOf: fileURL))
        print("This Url: \(fileURL)")
    }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

Comment: does not work currentDirectoryURL is file:/// while file url is file:///holder.txt

Comment: can you try with NSHomeDirectory and tell the result? `let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(file)`

Comment: the results are file:///Users/xdesss/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8C632FD2-2346-4FB4-8128-CC39A70B7618/data/Containers/Data/Application/21A8F235-C18F-4F58-B8A6-CD91356C2038/Projectv5/Project/holder.txt

Comment: Just to clarify, is your project an iOS app or a mac cocoa app?

Comment: the project i have to make is an ios app

Comment: It really doesn’t make sense using a .txt file with a mac folder path, because iOS apps are installed on the devices, so your .txt file need be copied to each install. What you want is to embed the file inside the iOS app and use ir as a local storage , right?